# Convolution with different dilation rates for each dimension

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, cnn, computer-vision

How can I get a dilated convolution with different dilation ratio on each axis?
Tensorflow/Keras would be best.

For example, the filter in the gif below would have the following properties:

- `kernel_size = (3,3)`
- `stride = 1`
- `dilation_rate = (4,2)`
  [image: Rectangular dilation]

Comment: Please explain more, why are trying to achieve different dialtion ration?

Comment: @DataFramed I have a time series that has been reshaped to 2D. We are experimenting with applying computer vision techniques to other domains.
The "image" is 21 x 12 (days x timesteps per day). So the hypothesis is that if we can use a 3x3 filter with dilution rate = (7,1), it would help pick up weekly patterns.